# want to create files in with id numbers and each file get row data with there id numbers match with file name

Tags: php

```
<?php
require(dirname(FILE).'/./config/config.inc.php');
  $sql = "SELECT  c.id_category, ROUND(AVG(p.price),0)
    
FROM
    psup_product p
INNER JOIN psup_category_product pc ON
    p.id_product = pc.id_product
INNER JOIN psup_category_product c ON
    pc.id_category = c.id_category
GROUP BY c.id_category";
    if ($results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql))
    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
        $somecontent = "id " . $row["id_category"]. " - Price " . $row['ROUND(AVG(p.price),0)']."\n";
        echo "id: " . $row["id_category"]. " - Price: " . $row['ROUND(AVG(p.price),0)']."<br>";
        $filename = "catid/$row.txt";
        
$myfile = fopen("$filename", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $somecontent);
fclose($myfile);
        
    }
 
?>
```

Hello experts, I use this script but when file create array.txt and only 1 file create guide us what mistake i'm doing..

Comment: Maybe you could post your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, you need to generate a different filename for each category. One possible approach is to replace `$filename = "catid/$row.txt";` with `$filename = "catid/".$row["id_category"].".txt";`.

Example, based on your code:

```
<?php
    require(dirname(FILE).'/./config/config.inc.php');
    $sql = "
        SELECT  c.id_category, ROUND(AVG(p.price),0)
        FROM psup_product p
        INNER JOIN psup_category_product pc ON p.id_product = pc.id_product
        INNER JOIN psup_category_product c ON pc.id_category = c.id_category
        GROUP BY c.id_category
    ";
    if ($results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $somecontent = "id " . $row["id_category"] . " - Price " . $row['ROUND(AVG(p.price),0)']."\n";
            echo "id: " . $row["id_category"]. " - Price: " . $row['ROUND(AVG(p.price),0)']."<br>";
            $filename = "catid/" . $row["id_category"] . ".txt";
            $myfile = fopen("$filename", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($myfile, $somecontent);
            fclose($myfile);
        }
    }
?>
```